# NuGet package manager with a specific version of .NET

Tags: nuget

It seems now that Visual Studio 2013 and .NET 4.5.1 are out, many NuGet packages now only support .NET 4.5 and above. We have older servers and are stuck on .NET 4.0 for the most part, so it has become increasingly difficult to update a package without either the package itself or one of its dependent packages failing because it's not targeted for .net 4.0.

Is there a way to tell the package manager to only get packages that are for the 4.0 framework?

I am guessing we will have to create an internal NuGet server and then painstakingly manually update packages in there for .NET 4.0, but there has to be a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

In your packages.config for each project you can specify your target framework version:

```
<package id="NLog" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
```

Comment: It seems like one of the updates of NuGet made this less of a problem.  Might even be fixed.

Comment: This gave me a clue: in my project I just needed to delete the 'requiresReinstall' attribute in the package element.