# Force NuGet to reference a .net framework 4.0 assembly in a 4.5 project?

Tags: nuget

I have two projects in my solution--one targets .net 4.0, the other targets .net 4.5.  They both reference the same NuGet package which contains both 4.0 and 4.5 binaries.

How can I get NuGet to reference the *same version*--4.0--in **both projects?**

Comment: Your project is 4.5, the nuget package has 4.0 and 4.5 versions, and yet you wish to reference the 4.0 version.  Why?

Comment: I have an other project in the same solution that targets the framework 4.0 and references the same thirdParty.

Comment: Good to know.  You can manually target the 4.0 version by browsing to the 4.0 version in the nuget package cache on disk, but i'm not sure if that's an optimal solution for you...

Comment: This answer might work for you, if you 1) update the config file as described 2) remove the reference from your 4.5 project, then 3) restore the nuget package?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20081509/1228

Comment: Restoring the nuget package will not modify the project file. So you will need to add the reference to the Net40 assembly by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the folder of the framework that you don't want to use (`ExcludeAssets`), and edit the `PackageTargetFallback` in your project.

In your project's csproj file:

```
<PackageTargetFallback Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net45'">
    $(PackageTargetFallback);net40
</PackageTargetFallback >
```

When referencing the package:

```
<PackageReference Include={package-ID} Version={version} ExcludeAssets="lib/$(TargetFramework)"/>
```

This way the package won't bring the binaries that you don't want, and the ones you want will be compatible.

**Note**: Taking dlls with a different target framework is not recommended.